# getting error while importing function from another file in node.js with ECMA

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I want to export these 2 functions in my app.js from callModule.mjs but while doing this i am always getting following error:

```
import {showUsers, callUserProfile} from "./callModule.mjs"
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Here is my app.js

```
import {showUsers, callUserProfile} from "./callModule.mjs"

showUsers();
callUserProfile();
```

here is my callModule.mjs

```
function showUsers(){
    console.log("this is show users function");
}

function callUserProfile(){
    console.log("This is user profile function");
}

export {showUsers, callUserProfile}
```

and here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "It is a beginner project for node js.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "manish agarwal",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.11",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

can anyone suggest what i am doing wrong here as i am new in Node.

thanks

Comment: try module.exports

Comment: i want to export using ECMA concept not common js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `esm` package:

1. Install esm: `npm install --save esm`
2. Enable esm: `node -r esm index.js`

More info & docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm